# OpenVPN client with static NAT

Tags: iptables, vpn, openvpn, nat

I have a an OpenVPN server installed on a Debian9 server on a VPS. 
I am able to connect and everything is routed through the tunnel. 
What I would like to do is to have all ports, or at least the ability to specify port ranges to be forwarded back to my client (assume there will only be one hosted connected to that VPN host).

To simplify, if someone were to access my VPS server IP address on port 8081, it will forward that to the client on port 8081.

That would basically be the equivalent of portforwarding on a home router or a DMZ host.

I have tried snat using iptables on the vps server and enable ipv4 ip_forward, but that didn't work.

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that you should try DNAT instead of SNAT. Check my answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1276877/tunnel-ports-thru-vps-running-openvpn-into-my-home-network-via-tomato-router).